# Controller functionality - User not logged in/ redirect to registration page (not wp_login)

Tags: user-registration, wp-redirect

I have a site **[here](http://azeverything.com)**...

If a user clicks on **Submit an Event** or **Send an Article**, they are re-directed to a 404 page because I have it set up to make the page private.

What I want to do is if the user is logged in, it goes to the correct page. But if the user isn't logged in, then they get directed to **[this registration page](http://azeverything.com/register-2)**.

I don't see any way to do this withing the settings of Wordpress.

Thoughts?

Comment: your site does not look good on 1024x768

Comment: are you okay with a plugin to wordpress, or do you need php code?

Comment: A plugin is fine if it does what I'm looking for. I've tried [**Redirect to login if not logged in**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-to-login-if-not-logged-in/) but that redirects to log-in page, from the moment the user steps on the website. I want the user to be able to get to the site, but if they click on a protected link, they get re-directed to the registration/log-in page.

Comment: And I'm aware of the resolution issues. Working on it.

Answer (score 1):

In that page's template, do something like...

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    $redirect = get_permalink(1); // where this integer is id of registration page 
    wp_redirect($redirect);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: +1 but could be done much earlier. `template_redirect` hook for e.g.

Comment: I went to pages, and clicked on the "text" editor for that page, and input that above code, but it didn't work. Am I missing something? (I'm a noob with WP customizations)...

Comment: No. You're not going to solve this without writing some code. Sounds like you're just looking for a plugin, in which case I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Then, you could try the [Quick Page Post Redirect Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/). Looking at the screenshots, it gives you rather granular functionality for redirection.